# Click events stop working after an Ajax load

Tags: jquery, ajax, events

I'm having some trouble with an Ajax script which disables my jQuery click events.

The following code works without the AJAX event:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('a.showtabinfos').click(function() {
        $('div.infos').removeClass("showtab").addClass("hidetab");  
        $(this).parent().find('div.infos').removeClass("hidetab").addClass("showtab");
    });
});
```

So I found in **the Jquery Faq** that:

http://docs.jquery.com/Frequently_Asked_Questions#Why_do_my_events_stop_working_after_an_AJAX_request.3F

But unfortunately, I'm not a JavaScript developer and I wasn't able to convert my 
jQuery events using 'event delegation'.
Can someone help me get my events to look like this:

```
$('#mydiv').click(function(e) {
    if($(e.target).is('a'))
    {
        fn.call(e.target,e);
    }
});

$('#mydiv').load('my.html');
```

---

**I tried another way to solve my problem**. In fact, what I am trying to do is simply open a `div` on click, by changing class.

**Html structure :**

```
-- div

------ a.showtabinfos

------ div.infos.hidetab  ( <div class='infos hidetab' ... </div> )

-- /div
```

When I click on `a.showtabinfo`s, I want `div.infos.hidetab` to become `div.infos.showtab` so, I tried doing this without jQuery, but JavaScript only.
I found a function on the web which helps me to change class:

```
function addClass(_element, _value)
{
    try
    {
        var oReg = new RegExp("^([\s]*)" + _value + "$");

        if(!_element.className)
        {
            _element.className = _value;
        }
        else
        {
            var bTest = oReg.test(_element.className);

            if(bTest)
            {

                _element.className = _element.className.replace(_value, "");
            }
            else
            {
                var newClassName;
                newClassName = _element.className;
                newClassName += " ";
                newClassName += _value;
                _element.className = newClassName;
            }
        }
    }
    catch(e)
    {

    }
}
```

and I tried to add a link like this:

```
<a class="showtabinfos" tabindex="1" id="imagetab-<?php the_ID(); ?>" href="Javascript: ;" onclick="addClass(this.parentNode.getElementsByClassName('infos'),'showtab');">CLICK HERE</a>
```

---

Can someone help me with the first or second way to solve my problem?

if you need more informations to answer me, just visit http://www.tom-portfolio.fr/demos/portfolio/category/portfolio/ to see what i am trying to do.
I just want to change the class name `<div class"infos hidetab"> to <div class="infos showtab">`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`Live`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) will add the click event to any elements currently on the page and any added in the future:

```
$('a.showtabinfos').live("click", function() {
    $('div.infos').removeClass("showtab").addClass("hidetab");  
    $(this).parent().find('div.infos').removeClass("hidetab").addClass("showtab");
});
```

I would also reccomend using [`delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) but can't show you exactly how to do it without some more of your markup because you need to basically attach the event to a parent container like so:

```
$("#parent_element_of_links").delegate(".showtabinfos", "click", function(){
    $('div.infos').removeClass("showtab").addClass("hidetab");  
    $(this).parent().find('div.infos').removeClass("hidetab").addClass("showtab");
});
```

**Edit:**

Looking at your page, I'm a bit unclear as to wether you have jQuery noConflict enabled or not, but I think this should do it:

```
jQuery.noConflict();
(function($) { 
    $('a.showtabinfos').live("click", function(e) {
        $('div.infos').removeClass("showtab").addClass("hidetab");  
        $(this).siblings('div.infos').removeClass("hidetab").addClass("showtab");
        e.preventDefault();
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: I tried the live function, and this is not working.
I didn't try the second one u posted after, i will do, but if you need to know more on my markup, just see it live on my website ( this is a site under construction, i get it open just to let you see the problem :
http://www.tom-portfolio.fr/demos/portfolio/category/portfolio/

I guess you have firebug. So try to change div.infos.hidetab to div.infos.showtab manually. That is exactlt what i want to happen when i click on an image.

Thanks !

Comment: Re, i tried your last Edit, but this is still not working.
It works if i disable the wordpress plugin "Ajax Comments-Reply".

Maybe should i take a look on this plugin to see why this is disabling my click events ? Any idea ?

Comment: Should i let you see the "comment.js' used by this plugin, which is generating new events, and so probably making troubles in my events ?

Comment: Yeah might be useful to see that comments.js.. Also, try switching any `$` signs for `jQuery` just incase it's a conflict issue.

Comment: Edit : Switching `$` to `jQuery` changes nothing. Both are working, except with with the plugin activated.

See comments.js here : http://www.tom-portfolio.fr/demos/portfolio/wp-content/plugins/ajaxcomment/comment.js

Comment: Alternatively, could i use a `<a onClick="parent().getElementsByClassName('infos').removeClass('hidetab').addClass('showtab')">` ... If the syntax were correct, it should be what i'm searching for ^^

Comment: Ah, in the first line of the ajaxcomment plugin is `function $() {` which will overwrite the jQuery `$` object - Please look at jQuery.noConflict at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/. If you see my edit above, this may be what you need to resolve the conflict.

Comment: Damn !! Thank you so much !
I changed `function $() {`  to `function $.noConflict() {` and it's now working !!!

Oh god .. i've been searching for a soooo long time ...
Thanks again !

Comment: BUT,
now i have an error displayed by my "web-developper tools", saying "$.noConflict is not a function"

And now, the "reply" link to answer doesn't work anymore ... Oh godd ... One problem solved, one new appears ... Rha. Need a coffee...

Edit : All the Javascripts links for comments are now not working. Submit, preview button, reply, etc ...
I may have made something wrong with the noConflict property ^^

Comment: No changing the function name to `function $.noConflict() {` will definitely not work.. Did you try the code in my edit above?

Comment: EDIT : I tried the code you gave me. It doesn't work. Nothing happend :(

Comment: Please try replacing your code for comment.js with this: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=AHiY6VyC

Comment: Your last Edit made the stuff Works dude !!! I'll make some tests, and i will confirm you if it works well. Anyway, thanks you so much for the help you gave to me !! ( if i can do something to thank you back, don't hesitate ! ). I will close my website in 30minutes ( if you wants to take a look on the unstylized result ^^ ). I don't wants google to start indexing my pages ^^

Comment: Great! The problem was that the comments.js function was overriding the jQuery $ function. To fix this, I had to remove any references to the $() function in comments.js and replace with something else.

Comment: Ok. Thank you so. I will keep this thread on favorite to keep the tip on mind ^^ Great Job dude !

Answer (score 9):

the live function is deprecated, you should use .on

e.g.

```
$(document).on('click', '.selector', function(){ 
   //Your code here
});
```